# Is there any efficient and universal way to get the remainder of a random number?

Tags: c, algorithm

My program has multiple threads which process messages. To let the threads receive messages evenly, I use a near global counter `count` which counts the number of event (not strictly accurate), and the pseudocode is like this:

```
unsigned int index = 0;
index = (++count) % thread_num;
queue_push(queue[index], event);
```

I am wondering whether there are more efficient way to get the index.I know if the `thread_num` is the power of `2`, the following code is very efficient:

```
index = (++count) & (thread_num - 1)
```

But if the `thread_num` is not the power of `2`, this will not apply (may ingore some threads).
Is there any more efficient and universal way to get the remainder of a random number? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that this is really a bottleneck?

Comment: @Beta: not sure, just want to know if there are a better and universal method.

Comment: @NanXiao There isn't. If you want to get the remainder, use the % operator.

Comment: Why do you need the threads to process messages 'evenly'?  Can they not simply pull messages off a common producer-consumer queue in usual way?

Comment: @MartinJames: the application frame is one producer thread, multiple consumer threads, and every consumer thread has a queue. The producer thread receives messages and dispatch the message to the queue of consumer thread. So is there any significant difference between two modles?

Comment: Did you know that it takes your processor several hundred times longer to actually put the work item in the queue, than it does to calculate `%`?

Comment: Btw, there is a universal and efficient way to calculate the remainder. That way is the `%` operator. If there was a better way, the compiler would use it when you write `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP noted, if `thread_num` is known to have *select* values during run time, then `index = (++count) % thread_num;` can be simplified.

Other simplification tricks apply to other numbers besides "power of 2" too.  But not in general.

If the compiler can determine select values (simple case: `thread_num` is a constant), modern compilers will employ various optimizations not quickly determine by the coder.

General answer: let the compiler optimize and use `%`.

```
index = (++count) % thread_num;
```

---

A universal alternate that *may* be more efficient.

If `%` is expensive, consider keeping `count` and `index` in a structure   (paired somehow) and update them together.

```
p.count++;
p.index++;
if (p.index >= thread_num) p.index = 0;
```